# Can you use EcomDev PHPUnit to unit test magento CE 1.9.x?

Tags: magento-1.9, ecomdev-phpunit, phpunit

On https://github.com/ecomdev/ecomdev_phpunit it says they support up to ce 1.7.x and ee 1.12.x. If the answer is no are there any tools to unit test magento 1.9.x?

Answer (score 1):

[EcomDev_PHPUnit](https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit) runs fine with CE 1.9

Other test suites / testing frameworks for Magento include:

- [xtest](https://github.com/code-x/Xtest)
- [Magento 2 Tests Backport](https://github.com/techdivision/TechDivision_MagentoUnitTesting)
- [Mage-Test](https://github.com/MageTest/Mage-Test)
- [Magento TAF](https://github.com/magento/taf)

Some are regularly maintained, others are not. Tools for approaches like BDD are not even included in this list, so it cannot be considered complete at all. Which one to choose depends pretty much on the individual project requirements and the developers' practical experience.